# How to prevent accidental deletion of contenteditable ul in IE10?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I want to have a contenteditable ul on a page. However, in Internet Explorer 10, if you click into it, select all with either the right click menu or CTRL+A, then delete, the ul element gets deleted off the page.

What is the best way to prevent this, or at least detect when it happens and insert a replacement ul?

Comment: It happens in all browsers, because the `li` is inside the contenteditable element and therefore editable thus deletable.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand that the `li`s are deletable. The problem I was having is that the `ul` itself gets deleted completely off the page; it doesn't show up with Inspect Element. In Chrome, even if you delete all the `li`s, you can still type into the `ul`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest intercepting the delete and backspace keys and doing the delete manually. The steps are:

- Get the selected range
- Adjust the ends of the range to lie within the editable `<ul>` element if they are outside
- Call `deleteContents()` on the range.

Note the following won't work on IE <= 8. If you need to support those browsers, you could use my [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy) library, which could also be used to simplify `deleteSelectedContent()` slightly.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/STcXa/3/

Code:

```
var editor = document.getElementById("editor");

function deleteSelectedContent() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
            var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            var editorRange = range.cloneRange();
            editorRange.selectNodeContents(editor);

            // Adjust selection range boundaries
            if (range.compareBoundaryPoints(Range.START_TO_START, editorRange) == -1) {
                range.setStart(editorRange.startContainer, editorRange.startOffset);
            }
            if (range.compareBoundaryPoints(Range.END_TO_END, editorRange) == 1) {
                range.setEnd(editorRange.endContainer, editorRange.endOffset);
            }

            range.deleteContents();
        }
    }
}

editor.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) {
    if (window.getSelection &&
            !window.getSelection().isCollapsed &&
            (evt.keyCode == 8 || evt.keyCode == 46)) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        deleteSelectedContent();
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: The way this is structured, using backspace or delete doesn't do anything unless any text is selected; backspace/delete from the cursor is prevented. This does help, though. I'd upvote you if I had enough reputation.