# limit the function of contenteditable

Tags: html, edit

Using
`<div contenteditable="true">
  This text can be edited by the user.
</div>`
is too broad. I would like to limit the content editing ability to just applying  and  tags without the ability of deleting content.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean that text can't be removed, but it can be added?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent accidental deletion of contenteditable ul in IE10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217493/how-to-prevent-accidental-deletion-of-contenteditable-ul-in-ie10)

Comment: The text should be static and the user should not be able to delete any of it. I would like to make text <b>  and <i>